# How to Run Multiple MySQL Versions on One Server

Tags: linux, mysql

How do I run multiple versions of MySQL on one server box? This is on a box running SUSE Enterprise Server 10. The initial installation of MySQL v5.0.45 was done via RPM. I am now being asked to setup a second MySQL running version 5.1.36 to run simultaneously with the previous version. I've downloaded the tarball for the binary distribution of MySQL v5.1.36.

I'm looking for specifics in how to set it up as well as any recommendations on managing the two different versions. Where I have one my.cnf or mutiple ones? Should I keep them in /etc or perhaps in the basedir of each MySQL instance? What is the best way to start and shutdown of both servers? etc.?

Comment: Would  virtualization be an option ?

Comment: Virtualization is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine.  Just specify separate conf, port, sock, etc.  Personally, I would probably maintain a `/etc/my.server1.cnf` and `/etc/my.server2.cnf` for individual server settings.  And for startup, just copy `/etc/init.d/mysqld` (or whatever it is called for Suse), and it should be just a matter of updating some variables to make the new script start the second server.

Comment: Hi Chad,

I am now looking at working with your idea of 2 separate my.cnf files. Since I'm using two different versions of MySQL does the list below include everthing I'd need to specify in the my.server2.cnf file [mysqld] section:

[mysqld]
basedir    = /opt/mysql
port       = 4444
datadir    = /opt/mysql/data
pid-file   = /opt/mysql/data/mysql.pid
socket     = /opt/mysql/data/mysql.sock
mysqld     = /opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
ledir      = /opt/mysql/bin
mysqladmin = /opt/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
user       = mysql
log-error=/opt/mysql/data/mysqld.log

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: That didn't format very well.  Why don't you update the question with the contents of the two files.  Make sure to specify different paths for datadir, socket, and pid-file.

Comment: I'm having a problem getting the /etc/init.d/mysql script to start the 2nd MySQL install. What do I need to change in it to have use an /etc/my.server2.cnf file instead of /etc/my.cnf which is always seems to grab instead?

Thanks
~D.

Comment: I figured it out. I'll post another question if I run into problems.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 5):

You can use mysqlmanager or mysqld_multi. mysqlmanager is more powerful but mysqld_multi is much easier to set up, and it's usually my choice

You just need one /etc/my.cnf like this (from mysql manual):

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/local/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/local/bin/mysqladmin
user       = multi_admin
password   = multipass

[mysqld2]
socket     = /tmp/mysql.sock2
port       = 3307
datadir    = /usr/local/mysql/var2

[mysqld3]
socket     = /tmp/mysql.sock3
port       = 3308
datadir    = /usr/local/mysql/var3

[mysqld4]
# ...
```

man page: [mysqld_multi — Manage Multiple MySQL Servers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqld-multi.html)

Comment: I'm working on this solution. How do I configure the [client] section of the /etc/my.cnf? Do I just omit it completely and have each client pass in a port and socket? Other suggestions?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Unless there's something you want to put there, it's better not to use it and specify in each client to which of the instances you want to connect. [client] can be nice to change default user, or if you have only one instance in a non-standard port